# Why are Odia Characters inserted/displayed as junk characters in my MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

**Update: SOLVED**

I just inserted charset=utfmb4 in my connection string and it worked.

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_name;charset=utf8mb4", "db_user", "db_pass")
```

phew!

---

### Original Question:

I'm building a contextual reference word bank related to my work field. I have a form with three text fields, using it I keep record of certain English words and phrases and their contextual meaning in my native Odia language.

Input form 1."Context"

Input form 2."English Word"

Input form 3. "Oriya Word"

In the live server the Odia words (say, ସହର) gets inserted as `à¬¸à¬¹à¬°`

The character encoding/collation is set to "utf8mb4_general_ci" (same as my localhost, where the texts get inserted/displayed as intended)

I tried adding the line

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

but it didn't help.

What's wrong?

**insert.php**

```
<?php

/* Attempt MySQL server connection.*/
try{
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db", "user_name", "passss");
    // Set the PDO error mode to exception
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . $e->getMessage());
}
// Attempt insert query execution
try{
    // Create prepared statement
    $sql = "INSERT INTO my_glossary (Domain, Keyword, Oriya_Meaning) VALUES (:Domain, :Keyword, :Oriya_Meaning)";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    
    // Bind parameters to statement
    $stmt->bindParam(':Domain', $_REQUEST['Domain']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Keyword', $_REQUEST['Keyword']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Oriya_Meaning', $_REQUEST['Oriya_Meaning']);
    
    // Execute the prepared statement
    $stmt->execute();
    echo "Records inserted successfully.";
} catch(PDOException $e){
    die("ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . $e->getMessage());
}
 
// Close connection
unset($pdo);
?>
<html>
<p><a href="backend.php">Add another</a><p>
```

The "Oriya_Meaning" field value is supposed to be in Odia script.

[The rows highlighed in green were imported from localhost db. Other rows were inserted via live webform.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmnwr.jpg)

`show create table my_glossary;` OUTPUT

```
  CREATE TABLE `my_glossary` (
  `Domain` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Keyword` varchar(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Oriya_Meaning` varchar(2000) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

Comment: What does `show create table my_glossary;` tell you? And how are you testing how the data gets saved to the DB? Are you sure it's not just a display problem when retrieving the data?

Comment: Using phpMyAdmin or whatever tool you use to look at your database, run the query `show create table my_glossary;` and show us the output by EDITING the output into your question

Comment: Hi @RiggsFolly, I have added the screenshot after running the query; please be patient, I can't figure out what/where is the output of that query.

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of or off site links to Code/Data/Error Messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). That query should show us the schema for that table, your images looses most of that

Comment: Output is in the `create table` cell, expand it and you should see more text

Comment: I posted the image because that's all the output I got:-  (Table  Create Table  
my_glossary  CREATE TABLE `my_glossary` (
  `Domain` varchar(25...

Comment: You see, thats the beginning of a Table Definition. Copy/Paste ALL of the contents of that cell

Comment: I edited my OP to include the output. Please see. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: You need to have the database's configuration changed to use `utf8mb4` as the default character set for connections and clients; if the server default is something else that will be applied to incoming connections. You may also want to explicitly state it in the DSN. Check the answers to the duplicate questions for details.

Comment: Probably not related to the issue, but your server is sending JSON responses with a `text/html; charset=UTF-8` MIME type, and your HTML is being served with just plain `text/html`. Both of those should be fixed.

Comment: Hi @miken32, thanks for pointing that out. But I absolutely have no idea what that means :|

Comment: See Mojibake in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored